# Can I update multiple fields in a table with aggregated data from other table, in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I figured out how to do one field at a time (see two update queries below). Is there a way to do this in a single query?

```
UPDATE upload_data sd
SET
  photo_count =
  (SELECT sum(photo_count) 
  FROM media_uploads mu
  WHERE mu.user_id=sd.user_id
  AND mu.date=current_date
  GROUP BY mu.user_id);


UPDATE upload_data sd
SET
  video_count =
  (SELECT sum(video_count) 
  FROM media_uploads mu
  WHERE mu.user_id=sd.user_id
  AND date_trunc('month', mu.date)=date_trunc('month', sd.date)
  GROUP BY mu.user_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this by `JOIN` with `UPDATE`. In postgresql as the [`UPDATE` syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html), it will be this way:

```
UPDATE upload_data sd
SET  sd.photo_count = m.photo_count,
     sd.video_count = m.video_count
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    user_id, 
    sum(photo_count) AS  photo_count, 
    SUM(video_count) AS video_count
  FROM media_uploads 
  WHERE mu.date = current_date
  GROUP BY user_id
) AS m 
WHERE m.user_id = sd.user_id;
```